# Code doesnt execute and pass through setWeekDate

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, calendar

I have a java code which uses the setWeekDate method in the Calendar class, but my code does not execute the function, it just stops before the setWeekDate method call. Any advice on that?

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 System.out.println("Before");
 c.setWeekDate(Integer.valueOf(requestDateElement[2]), requestCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR), 1);
 System.out.println("After");
```

I tried to print the two lines but only "before" is printed out.

Comment: Can you post a SSCCE demonstrating the problem in full? I was not able to replicate the problem with only the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

try executing the code in a try/catch block

```
try{
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         System.out.println("Before");
         c.setWeekDate(Integer.valueOf(requestDateElement[2]), requestCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR), 1);
         System.out.println("After");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and let us know if there is any exception